# Disable streaming of a shared video

Tags: windows-7, streaming, file-permissions, file-sharing

I work in a corporate office, I am in charge of distributing the training videos.  I have all 100+ training videos shared over the network.  The plant managers open the videos in WMP so it's essentially streaming off the computer where the videos are stored.  The issue is that the videos are on my personal PC. So the streaming bogs down my internet connection.  Is there any way to disable the streaming?

I want them to have to download the video to their workstations and then watch it.

Comment: I think you are trying to use the wrong solution. Move the videos to a proper corporate file-server (which also takes care of backups and you do not disrupt people when you shutdown or reset your workstation).

Comment: I am separate from IT. IT won't let me do that I already tried... we don't have a huge IT budget and the servers are being "pegged" already.

Comment: Try putting them up on Google Drive or Dropbox, if you can't get IT to host them. There is no way for your computer to tell the difference between downloading and streaming, the requests are identical.

Comment: You could YouTube them.

Comment: Some of the videos are 3 hours long and the files are pretty big. We want to keep it all in house.

Comment: If you want to keep it in house, then buy some hardware to host it.  Perhaps a NAS, or even an old workstation, and work with IT to get it implemented.

Comment: I understand I can move it. That's not the route I want to go. If anyone has a solution to the original question that's great. I understand what you guys are saying, but I don't want to go that way. So please stop suggesting it.

Comment: @Kryptos You don't understand, there is no solution to the original question, **there is no way for your computer to tell the difference between someone downloading your file to stream it and someone downloading your file to watch it locally on their computer**. Your only option is host the file not on your workstation so it does not effect you.

Comment: Why is your personal PC at the corporate office you work at?  Why do the files **have** to be hosted on your *personal* PC?  Are you being compensated for using your own personal equipment at work, for such a hardware intensive task?  Why is your IT department not handling this, as it is most definitely within the scope of their responsibilities?  These are all questions that you should be answering, if you want an answer that works within the parameters you have set up.  Otherwise, you are actually being a bit unreasonable.  You could always put the movies within a ZIP file...

Comment: @bon gart its my workstation, I do not own it. It's a company computer.

Comment: Ah... see, then that means it isn't your "personal" PC.  At any rate, I stick with my last statement.  Put each video in a .zip file, and that way they HAVE to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you could get users to download the video first (without streaming) is to instruct them to do so. There's no magic way to instruct their computers to download it first. And ***even if you did instruct them to do this, you would still experience lag in your connection***. There is no difference between "streaming" (playing *while* downloading) and downloading (playing the file *after* downloading) They're still downloading it from you and using bandwidth. (Read [@ScottChamberlain's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/642289/disable-streaming/642322#comment804229_642289))

You said you do not want to move the files off of your computer or move them to a cloud service, so you've essentially locked yourself out of all viable solutions.

---

However, an **alternative solution** to fix your slow network speed problem would be to put your computer behind a router and use QoS to limit file sharing services outbound. This would be taking place on TCP port 445. Their computers would simply take longer to buffer (while streaming) or download. The downside to doing this is **all** outbound file sharing traffic from your computer on this port would become throttled.